# Type arguments not being inferred from context

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I have a problem with generic extensions. I have simple `IMapping` interface and all mappings implements this interface. I want to simplify mocking for tests so I have created extensions for it. But the problem is that I get `The type arguments for method cannot be inferred from the usage.` error. I can specify types explicitly (then it works) but it shouldn't be necessary because IMHO i could be inferred from context (because of `where` constraint). Am I missing something?

```
public static void SetupRandomMapping<TMapping, TSource, TDestination>(this Mock<TMapping> mock)
    where TMapping : class, IMapping<TSource, TDestination>
{
    // next line does not work
    mock.SetupRandomMapping(It.IsAny<TSource>(), out var dummy);
}

public static void SetupRandomMapping<TMapping, TSource, TDestination>(this Mock<TMapping> mock, TSource source, out TDestination destination)
    where TMapping : class, IMapping<TSource, TDestination>
{
    // some code ...
}
```

`IMapping` looks like this:

```
public interface IMapping<in TSource, out TDestination>
{
    TDestination Map(TSource src);
}
```

Comment: Constraints are not used in inference, you have to specify type of `destination` parameter explicitly: `, out TDestination dummy`

Comment: What happens if you remove `TMapping` and replace it with `IMapping<TSource,TDestination>` ?

Comment: @NetMage, than it works but only for `IMapping<X, Y>` not for child interfaces such as `XToYMapping : IMapping<X, Y>`.

Comment: Then I'm afraid you have to specify types manually or create helper extension methods to handle child interfaces.